# Microstream 8 CDI @Store type

Tags: quarkus, cdi, microstream

Looking at a blog: https://openliberty.io/blog/2022/05/03/microstream-cdi-ext.html

This example mentions the annotation type @Store.

I'm using version 8 with JarkartaEE 10 and microprofile 6 so I'm using the cdi integration: microstream-integrations-cdi3

What happened to @Store type?  Is it obsolete or just didn't make the cut in V8?

Please note, I am looking for @Store, not @Storage.

Thanks

I tried using: microstream-integrations-cdi3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the `@Store` annotation is found under the [`microstream-cdi-extension`](https://github.com/microstream-one/microstream-cdi-extension) repo but it has, since, been archived (since 16 March 2022). It's no longer available in any CDI archives.